# Counting characters, a Java program and wc yield inconsistent results

Tags: java, linux, gnu-coreutils

I wrote a java program that counts the number of characters in a file. To check that the program is working correctly, I type this into the command line (linux) to check the number of characters:

`wc -m fileName`

from the man page for `wc`, I know that the newline character is included in the count.

Here is my java program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumOfChars {
  /** The main method. */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Check that command is entered correctly
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java NumOfChars fileName");
    }

    // Check that source file exists
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    if (!file.exists()) {
      System.out.printf("File %s does not exist\n", file);
    }

    // Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    int characters = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
      
      String line = input.nextLine();

      // The number of characters is the length of the line plus the newline character
      characters += line.length() + 1;
    }
    input.close();

    // Print results
    System.out.printf("File %s has\n", args[0]);
    System.out.printf("%d characters\n", characters);
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that sometimes the number of characters reported from using the java program is different from the number I get when using the `wc` command.

Here are two examples:

One that works. The contents of the file `text.txt` is

```
This is some text
This is some text
This is some text
This is some text
This is some text
This is some text
This is some text
This is some text
```

The command `wc -m text.txt` tells me that this file has **144** characters. This is good because when I execute the java program `java NumOfChars text.txt`, I am also told that the file has **144** characters.

One that doesn't work. The contents of file `Exercise06.java` is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

/** Converts a hexadecimal to a decimal. */
public class Exercise06 {
  /** Main method */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter a string
    System.out.print("Enter a hex number: ");
    String hex = input.nextLine();
    
    // Display result
    System.out.println("The decimal value for hex number "
      + hex + " is " + hexToDecimal(hex.toUpperCase()));
  }
  

  /** Converts hexadecimal to decimal.
      @param hex The hexadecimal
      @return The deciaml value of hex
      @throws NumberFormatException if hex is not a hexadecimal
    */
  public static int hexToDecimal(String hex) throws NumberFormatException {
    // Check if hex is a hexadecimal. Throw Exception if not.
    boolean patternMatch = Pattern.matches("[0-9A-F]+", hex);
    if (!patternMatch) 
      throw new NumberFormatException();

    // Convert hex to a decimal
    int decimalValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
      char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);
      decimalValue = decimalValue * 16 + hexCharToDecimal(hexChar);
    }
    // Return the decimal
    return decimalValue;
  }
  
  
  /** Converts a hexadecimal Char to a deciaml.
      @param ch The hexadecimal Char
      @return The decimal value of ch
    */
  public static int hexCharToDecimal(char ch) {
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
      return 10 + ch - 'A';
    else // ch is '0', '1', ..., or '9'
      return ch - '0';
  }
}
```

The command `wc -m Exercise06.java` tells me that this file has **1650** characters. However, when I execute the java program `java NumOfChars Exercise06.java`, I am told that the file has **1596** characters.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone provide me with some feedback?

**EDIT: Here is what I get when typing in `head -5 Exercise06.java | od -c`
[image]

Comment: `characters += line.length() + 1;` let me guess: the second file comes from a windows machine?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca nope. No windows machine? Would that make a difference?

Comment: the 2nd file has (based on what you've posted) 54 lines; the difference in `wc/java` counts is 54; as Federico has hinted at ... did the 2nd file come from Windows and if so are  you sure there aren't 2x EOL characters (\n\r) that  you need to be counting? what does `head -5 Exercise06.java | od -c` show as the EOL character(s)?

Comment: @Mr.Young I was hinting at the fact that windows uses two characters to go to a new line (as markp-fuso says). You should consider treating your file as a bunch of chars instead of as a bunch of lines.

Comment: try running dos2unix on the .java file (be sure to take a backup) and retry. As others have pointed out is probably due to different EOLs. If the difference was smaller (like 1 or 2 bytes, could've been also due to file encoding - old unicode extra chars).

Comment: About your edit, as you can see there are two newline characters for each line (a carriage return (`\r`) and a newline (`\n`), to be precise)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks for the info. No the second file isn't from windows. I typed the head command; check my original post for the results. If I count 2 EOL characters, then the count for the text.txt file will be wrong...wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Young you can test if the file contains CR+LF, and in that case count end line chars two times (like wc does).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Aw I see. I didn't understand what I was looking at. I've never used that command before. So you and markp-fuso are saying that this would happen if the file was written on a windows machine? I suppose that would explain why I'm having the issue with only a small number of files. I'm doing some exercises from a text book. For some of the exercises, I borrow code from the book's companion website. The author of that code must be using windows. Thanks!

Comment: @BigMike Good idea. I'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible explanations:

- It is possible that each line ends with more than one character, for example on Windows each line ends with CR + LF, whereas your program always counts exactly 1 line ending character.
- `wc` may assume a different character encoding than your program, possibly leading to different character counts for multi-byte characters.